# How do I make the case to regain first authorship?

Tags: advisor, authorship, interpersonal-issues

I am a senior Phd student in a very small lab consisting of me, my PI, and one other graduate student (one year under me). We began at an academic institution working on this paper related to my dissertation. I was always first author on this paper, and presented it to my committee as such. A former post doc who "contributed intellectually" but did minimal actual work for the final paper is second author, and the other grad student was third author. The other graduate student contributed significantly more work for this paper than the postdoc who left the lab due to lack of funds, so she asked if she could be moved to second author.

In a STUNNING move, my PI made her co-first author and kept the post-doc at second. I found this unfair, and when I went to talk to her, she revealed that she had promised her post-doc high authorship on the paper before she left, and also felt that the other graduate student contributed enough to be co-first. I had to no choice but to let it go.

The paper was rejected three times in its current form. The last journal told us if we added more patient numbers, they would reconsider it with the same reviewers. As a result, my PI added 200 more cases (we only started out with about 150 cases) from a cohort that I managed myself, processed, phenotyped, genotyped, multiplexed, etc. I did all the statistical data analysis, redid all the figures (that I had already made to begin with) and integrated these extra cases into the manuscript. The other graduate student, nor the postdoc had anything to do with these additional cases.

When I asked for my sole first authorship back, she blew up at me and told me it would demean the other graduate student by demoting her (which I felt is exactly what she did to me). We have an upcoming meeting and I need to know what my options are outside of her if she refuses to change the authorship list. Do I need to contact the department head and my committee about this? I told the other graduate student the situation and she is COMPLETELY fine with being second author, as she was never asking for first authorship to begin with as this paper is not at all related to her dissertation. She actually thinks its ridiculous that my PI is not seriously considering this request. I feel like she is trying to save face with her post-doc, and not giving me proper credit for my work.

Am I being unreasonable or do I have a case?

Comment: Hmmm. Actually, you should calm down and act in a more collegial manner. Think of authorship as cooperating, not competing, with others. You will have future opportunities to work alone. I suggest you take them.

Comment: It's not about competition. I feel like she is not recognizing the significant additional contributions I have made with this additional cohort. The effort is no longer equal and the author list need to reflect that...period.

Comment: OTOH, RAGE has seldom been a very effective academic strategy. What will you win? You are already (co) first author.

Comment: I'm not raging (even though the post may have seemed that way). I presented her with a very reasonable and logical argument, in which I was met with rage from HER. To me, having to put that this was a co-author effort in every future grant application, CV, etc, when I know it is not true will hurt no one's career but mine. Not to mention having to explain to my committee why I am no longer first author.

Comment: I appreciate your comments Buffy. This is why I posted this, to get the perspective of a PI.

Comment: Have you told your PI that the other graduate student has agreed to be second author? Could you also have an offline conversation with post doc and ask if she would consider third author position?

Comment: Also, I think you can avoid giving the impression of rage by changing words like “screwed” here...

Comment: Dawn, you are right. I have adjusted the wording in my post. Thank you for your comments. I have not let my PI know yet that the other graduate student is fine with being second author. I had the conversation with her very recently. I was going to tell her at our upcoming meeting. She has agreed to write her an email if necessary, and let her know that she is fine with this decision. I have also not reached out to the post-doc, but I can. I'm not sure how she will react though.

Comment: How many authors are there total? And where is the PI (is she your PhD advisor) in that list?

Comment: There are 18 authors total and she is the corresponding (last) author listed. Yes, she is my PhD advisor.

Comment: For so many questions like this one, my first thought is: "Don't you have a dissertation / thesis committee, and other faculty to talk to?" If so, talk to them! If not, this should be something your department really has to work on, and in the meantime, you'll probably benefit from talking to other faculty, who can help talk to your PI. Good luck!

Comment: And have you considered the possibility that the other student (co-author) is just yielding to your pressure and wants the problem to go away? And are you just digging a deeper hole for yourself, longterm, by continuing the pressure? What I think you will gain is minimal. What I think you could lose is more important.

Comment: To me, this is not a minimal gain. Every time I write in my CV, grant application, etc I have to note that this was an equal effort between me and her, which it is  clearly not. If she had volunteered to maybe integrate those cases into the manuscript and redo analyses, I could see her keeping her spot, but she did not. Her and I are good friends and from the beginning, she did not want a co-first author spot. She wanted second author. She knows how hard I've worked on this paper alone and she was not surprised that I asked for this. She said she actually expected it because it made sense.

Comment: I"m not going to yield to a co-author when I know I should be first author. I feel that's short changing myself and my work. I feel my PI is being unethical by giving credit where it's not due so "everyone wins". I just don't see it like that and I don't think it's fair. Thank you for your opinion though.

Comment: Good luck to you.

Comment: Thank you for giving me your opinion Buffy. This will help me in my meeting with her.

Comment: What is meant by “co-first”?  An author list is a list with a first, second, third, etc.

Comment: In the paper, there's a symbol that indicates that the first two names 'contributed equally' and are considered co-first authors instead of first and second.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the case that agreements about author order should be renegotiated after a major reworking of the paper. Because this is essentially a new paper, you might convince all parties to change the order. If you regularly correspond with the post doc, you might ask her if she would consider the new author list.

However, if she does not wish to change, you should accept this gracefully. Frankly, you have already missed the appropriate window for renegotiating author order. Author order should be determined before the work (or rework) is done. 
Trying to change the order after work is complete is inappropriate because if, for instance, the third author wanted to keep her place as second, she no longer has any opportunity to do so.

The correct course of action would have been to propose being reinstated as first author before you did the work on the 200 new cases. At this stage, your negotiating power would have been higher. In addition, anyone who wanted to maintain co-first author or second author position could have helped you with the work. It seems you have learned a hard lesson; I hope you can avoid letting it ruin your relationship with your PI.